# Oscillatory Functions and Limits

Tags: calculus, limits

I recently stumbled upon this problem:

lim x->0  (sin(1/x)/sin(1/x))

I thought whether this be one or undefined. Because being an oscillatory function exact values aren't known meaning sometimes it will be zero and sometime undefined.But at the same time we caan cancel numberator and denominator to get 1 as answer. What is the right approach?

Comment: "But at the same time we can cancel num(b)erator and denominator to get 1 as answer": can you? The function is definitely $1$ on its domain, and this is isn't any different than evaluationg the limit as $x\to 0$ of a partial function that has domain $\{x\in\Bbb R\,:\, x\ne 0\land \frac1{\pi x}-\frac12\notin\Bbb Z\}$ and that is $1$ on its domain. Does the fact that the point you are trying to evaluate the limit on is a cluster point of the complement of the domain of the function constitute a problem, according to the definitions you were given in your course?

Comment: For what it's worth, this is Exercise 21 on p. 183 of the 1952 10th edition (last edition) of [**A Course of Pure Mathematics**](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.239784/page/n197/) by Godfrey Harold Hardy. However, the answer to your question depends on how limits of functions (of a real variable) are defined. Most authors, especially in relatively elementary (i.e. non-research level) literature, the answer is NO. However, I'm pretty sure that if I took the time to look around a bit, then I could find some places where the answer would be YES (with limit $1).$